# MPAndroidChart - how to get zoom level?

Tags: android, android-studio, view, zooming, mpandroidchart

Is there any way to find out that what the **zoom level of the chart** is in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)? and after that zoom out do nothing?

**I need to call zoom out until zoom of chart get back to normal**

Comment: if you're using BarChart or LineChart  then use `yourChart.fitScreen();` to zoom out programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

i think, there is no method to find zoom level of chart.

You can reset the zoom by calling `chart.fitScreen()`. This will reset the chart viewport to it's original state.You can call `fitScreen()`.

OTHER FUNCTIONS :

Setting scale minima to 0f means you can zoom out too infinity. Setting it to 1f means you can zoom out exactly as much to see the whole chart.

So you should call:

```
setScaleMinima(2f, 1f)
```

which only sets the zoom bounds, but does no actual zooming.

For zooming, call

```
zoom(float xzoom, float yzoom, float xpos, float ypos)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
    ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler = myChart.getViewPortHandler();
    float scaleX = viewPortHandler.getScaleX();
    float scaleY = viewPortHandler.getScaleY();
```

where scaleX and scaleY are the returned value of the zoom factor used in:

```
myChart.zoom(scaleX, scaleY, xValue, yValue, axis);
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin code to zoom out to maximum level

```
while(!chart.isFullyZoomedOut){
    chart.zoomOut()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

barChart.getScaleX();
barChart.getScaleY();

Note: The minimum value is 1.0

Answer (score -1):

thanks to @Amit Vaghaela this code worked for me

```
chart.setScaleMinima(0f, 0f);
chart.fitScreen();
```